# Fill background with different color if div contains "a word"

Tags: javascript

I want to fill background of one element (it is a class) with white color if another class contains word

Part of code in html page:

```
<div class="Class where I want to color background">
 <div class="Class where I have text">
  <a href="URL">Some text Word</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code I thought I could use:

```
var FindWord = "Word";
if ($(".NameOfClass").text().indexOf(FindWord) > -1)
{
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

I combined from two places this code above but as predictable it's not working. I now I have to put name of the other class but I don't know how and also I presume whole statement is incorrect.

*Edit:*
I inserted part of code where I want to find text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work:

```
var FindWord = "Word";
if ($(".NameOfClass").text().indexOf(FindWord) > -1)
{
     $('.background-class').css('background-color', '#fff');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var FindWord = "Word";
console.log('FindWord result',$(".NameOfClass").text().indexOf(FindWord));
if ($(".NameOfClass").text().indexOf(FindWord) > -1)
{
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

your

```
$(".NameOfClass").text().indexOf(FindWord)
```

is not properly working so console.log it. (I Guess)If ".NameOfClass" is a div, you have to use html() instead .text()

Answer (score 1):

The problem is **which** `event` will trigger the code to run.

In my example it always runs when the page loads:

```
<body style='background-color:black'>
<div class='myClass'>
  some text some text Word some text some text
</div>
</body>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var FindWord = "Word";
  if ($(".myClass").text().indexOf(FindWord) > -1) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  };
})
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tedmanowar/kefL4zsg/